# How to select child with Sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I can't select a child in Sass with last-chidl/first-child or something else.

I want to select a nav in a a navigation bar.

I think i have a big misunderstanding  but i don't know which.

I think it's ease but I assure you I already checked online...

I have try it to select and only but red background to the first nav in Sass.

```
<div class="navigation">
      <h2 id="logo">Resto</h2>
      <nav>
        <ul>
               <!-- Need red background -->
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <nav>
                 <!--  dont need red background-->
      </nav>
</div>
```

My Sass

```
.navigation nav:first-child{
    background: red;
}
```

I tried it to :

```
.navigation 
    > nav:first-child{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Your `<H2>` element is the first child, not your nav element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector `.navigation nav:first-child` selects the `nav` as a first child of `.navigation`. But it doesn't exist because `h2` is the first child. Use `:first-of-type` selector instead.

```css
.navigation nav:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
      <h2 id="logo">Resto</h2>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>RED</li>      
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>NON RED</li>      
        </ul>
      </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: thank @protob you for your answer it helped a lot! I can"t vote for now but when I'll be able I will :).